# Does an Egyptian citizen require a Transit visa for Istanbul airport?

Tags: transit-visas, egyptian-citizens, isl

I hold an Egyptian passport and am travelling from Cairo to Istanbul then to London (round trip). I'm using Turkish Airlines for all my flights. I will layover less than two hours each time.

Do I need a transit visa?

Answer (score 2):

Short response: No, foreign citizens flying to Europe and transiting Istanbul don't need a visa given that they stay in the transit zone of the airport.