# Egyptian with a layover in Istanbul

Tags: transit-visas

My husband is Egyptian, traveling for the first time to the USA with his visa. We have a layover in Istanbul and the airline is Turkish Airlines. Does he need any type of transit visa for the layover in Istanbul?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does an Egyptian citizen require a Transit visa for Istanbul airport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/41901/does-an-egyptian-citizen-require-a-transit-visa-for-istanbul-airport) See also [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/120441/does-an-egyptian-need-a-visa-to-transit-in-istanbul?rq=1).